# Checking for method parameter at runtime with SFINAE

Tags: c++11

I know one could check the existence of a particular method using expression SFINAE in C++11 as follows.
What I can't find though, is an example to do the same, checking method arguments as well. In particular I would like to match a method that takes a const parameter.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    void method() const
    {
      return;
    }
};


template <typename T, typename = std::string>
struct hasMethod
        : std::false_type
{

};

template <typename T>
struct hasMethod<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().method())>
        : std::true_type
{ };

int main() {

    std::cout << hasMethod<A>::value << std::endl;
}
```

In reality I would like the `hasMethod::` to match

```
    void method(const Type& t) const
    {
      return;
    }
```

What is the syntax to pass to `decltype`?
I have tried:

```
struct hasMethod<T, decltype(std::declval<T>().method(const int&))>
        : std::true_type
```

but it obviously doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean by "*that takes const parameter*" ? a parameter that isn't a non-const lvalue reference?

Comment: usually, one would type `decltype(std::declval<T>().method(std::declval<Type>()))` for that

Comment: yes Piotr, I intend for example a method name with the signature `void method(const int&)`

Comment: does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37054828/3953764) help?

Comment: [example here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e2615e6a17d35b8f)